# How to get latest commit hash from remote?

Tags: git

I wish to retrieve the latest commit hash on the remote repository, regardless of branch.

I've tried `git ls-remote <remote>` and `git ls-remote --tags <remote>` but both of these seemingly sort by tag name, which does not make it possible to find out which is the latest.

For example on Github, you can go to Insights / Network and get a graph that includes all branches and commits in these -- however, working in that gui is obviously not ideal - but the data should be there somehow.

Is there a way to get the latest commit hash from remote irregardless of branch?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Recent versions of git (don't know which - 2.14 didn't, 2.21 does) allow a "--sort" option in ls-remote. You can easily do:

```
git ls-remote --sort=committerdate
```

But be aware - if it is necessary to look into objects to achieve the sorting (as in the above example), the objects must be locally available. Otherwise you will get an error message "fatal: missing object". So make sure you always do a `git fetch` before you use it.

To be honest - since you must make sure to have all remote branches locally fetched before being able to use this, this is not much better than simply doing `git branch -r --sort=committerdate` after a fetch. Only obvious difference is that ls-remote directly shows the commit hash you are searching for, while with git branch you will have to wrap into a git rev-parse like this:

```
git rev-parse `git branch -r --sort=committerdate | tail -1`
```

Comment: +1 This is the most straightforward way to do it. As an alternative, you can invert the sort order by prefixing the key with `-` and using `head` instead: `git rev-parse $(git branch -r --sort=-committerdate | head -1)`

Comment: Yeah, your last command seemed to work well for me. I get the latest commit hash regardless - but as you say, I've got to do `git fetch` first.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `git show` with remotes:

```
git show origin/master
```

Will show you the last commit of `origin/master`

EDIT:
To get the "absolute" latest commit, I'd do something along the lines of:

```
git log -n 1 $(git branch -r)
```

Which will log all the remote branches (`git branch -r`). But will keep just the first commit (`-n 1`).

I am not too sure of the chronological order, but on my repo is seems to give me the latest one.

Another option, more "oneliner-like" would be:

```
git show -s --pretty='format:%ci %s %h' $(git branch -r) | sort -r | head -n 1
```

Which will list the last commits of each remote branch formatted in a way that the date is first, then sorted (on the date) and keeping the first

Comment: Sorry. I phrased my question wrong. I want to get the latest commit hash on any commit on any branch on remote. Does that make more sense? I'll edit it.

Comment: Note: You might have to `git fetch` first, to ensure that the tracking branch is actually in sync with the latest remote branch.

Comment: indeed @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Edited to match your need @cbll

Comment: Won't this get the latest commit locally, rather than the latest on remote?

Comment: SPOILER: All the commits are saved locally when you run `git fetch`. 
But that will get all the commits on which the remote branches point to, which says nothing about if these commits are accessible by local branches

Comment: In a simplified nutshell, a Git repo is composed of a bunch of objects called commits, related together in a linked list fashion. There are also objects called "branches", which are just a flat text file with as content a commit hash.

Comment: @padawin Not sure why, but with your last two commands I'm thrown back `fatal: unrecognized argument: ->`, which I do not understand..

Comment: Is the output of `git branch -r` empty?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191902/discussion-between-padawin-and-cbll).

Answer (score 1):

Fetch from the remote, "origin" for example,

```
git fetch origin
```

Print the information of all remote branches under "refs/remotes/origin",

```
git for-each-ref refs/remotes/origin
```

Sort by committer date in descending order,

```
git for-each-ref refs/remotes/origin --sort="-committerdate"
```

Get the latest,

```
git for-each-ref refs/remotes/origin --sort="-committerdate" | head -1
```

If you consider tags too, the above result may not be the latest commit. To find out the latest commit pointed at by tags,

```
git for-each-ref refs/tags --sort="-*committerdate" | head -1
```

Note that a tag may be annotated, so here `*` is necessary.

You might be also interested in refs under other namespaces, like abandoned pull requests. Compare the latest commits of each group of refs and get the latest one among them.

Answer (score 0):

```
git show <branch you want> --format=%h -s
```

--format=%h gets you just the shortened hash, use %H for the full hash

-s strips off the other cruft in show command

Answer (score 0):

Based off of @padawin 's answer using oneline:
`git log --oneline -5 origin/dev`